# 8086 microprocessor; intel

Tags: x86

give the appropriate DEBUG commands that will find out the number of COM and LPT(printer) ports installed in your PC. list their port address?

it may seem like a homework problem, but it is not.i am studying microprocessors,and i am not getting anything, so i have to learn by decoding the solutions.
so kindly post the answers.. thanks.

Comment: well,its not a homework problem,coz had it been, i would have done it by now as someone from my institute would surely have got this. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the BIOS data segment `0040:0000` to `0040:0300`, which contains lots of useful configuration stuff. Unless you have an operating system that overwrites that memory, but that's not probable.

For example the amount of free memory in kilobytes as a `uint16_t` at `0040:0013` (uh oh, unaligned memory ;)). Some memory cells below are the port numbers for `lpt*` and `com*`.

Comment: Technically, the BIOS data area at 40:0000 doesn't depend on MS-DOS in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the serial port addresses (up to four) are the first thing in the BIOS data segment (0040H), followed by the parallel port addresses (LPT).

[image]

Here you can see serial ports at 03F8, 02F8, 03F8, and 02E8 followed by the printer ports.